# When there is no internet I want to read the correct current geolocation lat,long of device in ReactNative

Tags: android, react-native

`I am using the below library to fetch the current geolocation in android device
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
Now when device is connected to internet code is returning the current geolocation of device.
But device is not connected to internet react native code is not giving the current geolocation of device.

```
const getCurrentLocation = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
                resolve({ latitude, longitude });
            },
            error => {
                console.error('Error getting location:', error);
                reject(error);
            },
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0 }
        );
    });
};
```

`

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: What do you mean with geo location? Something different than latitude, longitude?

Comment: Geo location is when you want to know street, town. The gps chip will give you coordinates (lat,lon) of course also without internet connection. Go to the forests.. to see. Gps has nothing to do with internet.

Comment: Are you requesting the right permissions and have the user allowed them?

Comment: Geolocation API depends on the device's internet so it's required to check if the network available before requesting new location coordinates.

Comment: You can simply cache the last device location with Async Storage then use that cached location in case of no internet available.

Comment: I mean lat and long. I want the lat and long without the network and internet avaiable.